# get age of given file

Tags: command-line, files, timestamps

How can I get the age of a given file in, at least, days?

I'm well aware of `ls -lh` and similar commands.  I want something that will work sort of like this:

```bash
getfage <FILE> # prints out '12d' (12 days)
```

Also, this needs to be somewhat cross-platform since I'd also like to use this under Mac OS X, but the primary use-case is on my Linux-box.

**NOTE**

Since Linux doesn't track creation time, I'm looking for two-fold solution: one for *mtime* (linux)--that is *the last time said file was modified*--and one for Mac OS X, which can either deal with *mtime* or creation time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do a ls and then sort the results by date created?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created)

Comment: @slm That's specifically about creation time, it doesn't go into computing the age on the command line.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to find creation date of file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91197/22222).

Comment: @terdon, not really.  See my **NOTE** above.

Comment: @AlexejMagura and how do the answers in the dupe not do for you? `stat` gives you all you need right?

Comment: @terdon good point.

Comment: Read `man stat`. Parsing `ls` output is a well known Bad Idea. The number of columns changes, depending on the age of the listed item!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Unix doesn't keep track of a creation date. The only information that's available is typically the last times the files was:

1. Accessed
2. Modified
3. Changed

> - Access - the last time the file was read
> - Modify - the last time the file was modified (content has been modified)
> - Change - the last time meta data of the file was changed (e.g. permissions)

(*[From this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2465/394)*)

You can get dates related to a particular file using the `stat` command.

#### Example

```
$ stat ffmpeg 
  File: `ffmpeg'
  Size: 19579304    Blocks: 38248      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 10356770    Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (  500/    saml)   Gid: (  501/    saml)
Access: 2013-11-26 10:49:09.908261694 -0500
Modify: 2013-11-02 17:05:13.357573854 -0400
Change: 2013-11-02 17:05:13.357573854 -0400
```

#### OSX and HFS

If you're using OSX the filesystem that's used under that Unix is [HFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_File_System). This is one of the few (that I'm aware of) that keeps the creation date within the filesystem, along with modification time etc. similar to other Unixes.

*excerpt*

> A File Record stores a variety of metadata about the file including its CNID, the size of the file, three timestamps (when the file was created, last modified, last backed up), the first file extents of the data and resource forks and pointers to the file's first data and resource extent records in the Extent Overflow File. The File Record also stores two 16 byte fields that are used by the Finder to store attributes about the file including things like its creator code, type code, the window the file should appear in and its location within the window.

#### Timestamps

Time stamps are always maintained in the filesystem, so you're limited by whatever time tracking is offered through them (EXT3, EXT4, XFS, etc.).

#### Filesystems

If you're ever curious take a look at this Wikipedia topic titled: [Comparison of file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems). It has the most extensive list of filesytems I'm aware of along with a nice table of the various features and the status of whether it's supported or not within a given filesystem.

#### References

- [How to find creation date of file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91197/22222)
- [How do I do a ls and then sort the results by date created?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20460/how-do-i-do-a-ls-and-then-sort-the-results-by-date-created)
- [List files created on Sundays](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50235/list-files-created-on-sundays)
- [Get file created/creation time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/get-file-created-creation-time)
- [Why does Unix time start at 1970-01-01?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26205/why-does-unix-time-start-at-1970-01-01/87417#87417)

Comment: Thanks for the update, that helps. Actually, I read [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/397442/) that ext4 can keep creation dates but this has not been implemented in the kernel yet.

Comment: @terdon - yeah it makes sense that some filesystems would support it. It seems long overdue to me, I understand in the past why it was left out, but everything has advanced so much since the beginning that it doesn't make sense to explicitly not have this. Also you can disable the support for access time so it could be implemented similarly and then disabled if you really didn't want it.

Comment: As of now (2023), running 'stat' on a file stored on an ext4 filesystem (kernel 5.15) prints a 'Birth' date.

Answer (score 37):

OSX keeps track of file creation, but most other unices don't, so there's no way to know the elapsed time since the file creation. You can obtain the elapsed time since its last modification on just about any operating system.

There's no portable shell utility to retrieve a file's modification time, except `ls` which has output that's nigh-impossible to parse. Under Linux, the following command prints the age of a file:

```
echo $(($(date +%s) - $(date +%s -r "$filename"))) seconds
echo $((($(date +%s) - $(date +%s -r "$filename")) / 86400)) days
```

Under Linux, you can use `stat -c %Y -- "$filename"` as a synonym of `date +%s -r "$filename"`.

OSX's `date` and `stat` commands are different. You can use the following command:

```
echo $(($(date +%s) - $(stat -t %s -f %m -- "$filename"))) seconds
echo $((($(date +%s) - $(stat -t %s -f %m -- "$filename")) / 86400)) days
```

Non-embedded Linux systems and OSX have Perl installed by default.

```
perl -l -e 'print -M $ARGV[0], " days"' "$filename"
perl -l -e 'print 86400 * -M $ARGV[0], " seconds"' "$filename"
perl -l -e '$mtime = (stat($ARGV[0]))[9]; print time - $mtime, " seconds"' -- "$filename"
```

Comment: Does this depend on the OS or the filesystem? [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91200/22222) Q&A seems to imply that the filesystem keeps them but the kernel needs to provide a method for accessing them.

Comment: @terdon - see my updates.

Comment: @terdon Both. That Q&A you link is correct, current filesystems have been tracking the creation time for a while now. In FreeBSD, you can actually get at this from `stat`, in Linux the syscall has not been reworked so you have to resort to hacking with `debugfs`.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner With the caveat that the creation time in the filesystem is often not the creation date in the application, as many applications use create-new-then-move as the method to save a new version rather than overwrite-in-place.

Comment: First example echo command which gives file age in seconds worked, but the other variant (third echo command) didn't work for me under Ubuntu 20 in a Bash shell script.

Comment: @Jan You mean the perl command? What happens? There's no error checking so this just prints ` days` if the file name is invalid.

Answer (score 10):

Based on answer by Gilles, here is a bash function that returns file age in seconds or error.

```bsh
function fileAge
{
    local fileMod
    if fileMod=$(stat -c %Y -- "$1")
    then
        echo $(( $(date +%s) - $fileMod ))
    else
        return $?
    fi
}
```

Comment: Neat function , easy to adapt by adding simple division to see age in Hour, Days, week  ....

Answer (score 2):

```
stat -c %Y <filename>
```

look at `man stat` for `-c` (format) options

Answer (score 1):

If you just want output as *12d* or *12 days* I use this...

```
filename=/path/to/your/file.txt
now=$(date +%s)
modified=$(date -r "$filename" "+%s")
delta=$((now-modified))
printf 'Created %d days ago\n' $((delta/86400))
printf 'Created %dh:%dm:%ds ago\n' $((delta/3600)) $((delta%3600/60)) $((delta%60))
```

Comment: You don't really seem to be adding anything to Gilles's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stat -f%B`, `ls -lU`, or `mdls -n kMDItemFSCreationDate` to see the creation (birth) time in OS X:

```
$ stat -f%B file
1402340803
$ ls -lU file
-rw-r--r--  1 admin  staff  108514 Jun  9 22:06 file
$ mdls -n kMDItemFSCreationDate file
kMDItemFSCreationDate = 2014-06-09 19:06:43 +0000
$ echo $((($(date +%s)-$(stat -f%B file))/86400))
10
```

Answer (score 0):

For standard Unix, `stat -c %Y` as seen in other answers gets you the 'last modified' time.  But for some circumstances you might want the 'inode change time' - this is when the metadata last changed.  It gets updated when you first make the file and then when you do things like `chmod` (which, most of the time, you won't be doing - so in many circumstances it stays as the original creation time).  That can be output with `stat -c %Z`.

Comment: There's no `stat` command in the UNIX standard. Serveral Unices have a `stat` command. The zsh shell has a `stat` builtin. But all have completely different APIs. The `stat` implementation that understands `-c %Y` is the GNU own (GNU standing for GNU's Not UNIX), though busybox also added a `stat` applet with a similar API

Answer (score 0):

Came across this today.

The Linux stat command now seems to have a birth date:

```
    $ stat myfile.ext
  File: myfile.ext
  Size: 4091        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 0,38    Inode: 5476021     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/chandana)   Gid: ( 1000/chandana)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Access: 2022-11-11 14:07:03.744610297 +1100
Modify: 2022-11-11 14:06:45.516562357 +1100
Change: 2022-11-11 14:06:45.519562365 +1100
 Birth: 2022-11-11 14:06:45.516562357 +1100
```

Comment: As mentioned in [the accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102692/116858), the `stat` command is only half of the issue, the filesystem must also support storing the relevant metadata. You don't mention what filesystem you use, nor what Linux you are using. BusyBox `stat` on e.g. Alpine Linux does not mention birth date, for example.