# Updating last modified time of a file

Tags: shell, files, touch

I have created a script to read 15 pcap files from a folder and merge then into one file using mergecap command. I want the merged file to have the creation time same as the first file of the 15 files and the last modified time same as the last 15th file. W.R.T [Changing a file's "Date Created" and "Last Modified" attributes to another file's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118577/changing-a-files-date-created-and-last-modified-attributes-to-another-file)

I have got how to modify the file times, but this will change all file times to that of the first file. touch -m command needs to be used here , but I cant see how to save the last modified time from the last file and put this to to the merged file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest : you could use :

```
touch -r Referencefile  THEFILE
```

to give THEFILE the same time as Referencefile
so:

```
rm -f Referencefile
echo > Referencefile  #to set the creation time
#...do your captures here, then concatenate into THEFILE ....
echo >> Referencefile #to set the modification time
touch -r Referencefile THEFILE
```

But if you prefer to have a more flexible way:

To have a "reliable" way to get the time of a file in a "portable" format, not depending on if the file last changed within 6 months, etc:

```
tar cf - file  | tar tvf -
```

so you could do this to get a time suitable for touch:

```
gettouchdate () { 
 tar cf - "$1" | tar tvf - | tr ':' ' ' \
  | awk '{mm=sprintf("%02d",(match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",$5)+2)/3) ;
          print $10 mm $6 $7 $8 $9 ;}'
}
#firstdate=$(gettouchdate "/path/to/FIRSTFILE")
lastdate=$(gettouchdate "/path/to/LASTFILE")
touch -r /path/to/FIRSTFILE  THEFILE
touch -m "$lastdate" THEFILE
```

Comment: I should add that on linux, you don't have the creation time... you have in POSIX: "Each file has three distinct associated timestamps: the time of last data access, the time of last data modification, and the time the file status last changed." (thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842195/how-to-get-file-creation-date-time-in-bash-debian )