# Solaris script - modified date file age

Tags: shell-script, files, solaris, test

I have a bash script on a Solaris server to provide an alert if a file is in a folder location for longer than 5 minutes.

```
if [ -f $1 ]
then
a=0
else
a=1
```

However, it is throwing a lot of false positives so I need to know how to add an additional filter when looking for a file to anything which was modified / created longer than 5 minutes ago.

If a file in x folder location is older than 5 minutes, I would like the script to report that.

**This question is not the same as the "possible duplicate" as I am requesting assistance with Solaris Linux and that ticket is referencing MAC and Linux, the commands mentioned there are not working in my Solaris box!**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get age of given file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102691/get-age-of-given-file)

Comment: @Panki I am using Solaris which seems to have a different command set - that's why it is not the same as that ticket, thank you for linking though, interesting stuff

Comment: @Thomas_ please see the help section on [merging accounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: Are you using Solaris 11, or 10? (or 9 or 8?!?)

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can work around it by manually creating a temporary file that's dated to five minutes ago, then ask `find` for files that are *not* newer than your temporary file:

```
tempfile=$(mktemp)
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]
then
  echo "Error creating temporary file; exiting"
  exit 1
fi
touch -t $(( $(date  +%Y%m%d%H%M) - 5 )) "$tempfile"
find /your/path -type f ! -newer "$tempfile"
rm "$tempfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all files in /foo which are older than 5minutes

```
find /foo -type f  -mmin +5
```

Comment: responds with : find: bad option -mmin

Comment: @Thomas_ If the default Solaris `find` doesn't support `-mmin`, maybe you can install GNU `find`? (https://www.opencsw.org/packages/findutils/)

Comment: @Thomas_  Are you using `/usr/bin/find` by default?  Try `/usr/xpg4/bin/find` instead.

Comment: [newer Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/find-1.html) do have -mmin in the xpg4 version; Solaris 10: no; Solaris 11: yes